# Can an Artificer imbue multiple objects with the same kind of infusion?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, artificer, artificer-infusions

I'm playing an artificer, and I want to use one of my known infusions twice (i.e. imbuing multiple objects with the same kind of infusion). Is this allowed, or not?

Specifically, I want to put the Enhanced Defense infusion on my shield, and then imbue my armor with the Enhanced Defense infusion as well. Does this work or not?

Comment: Note that regardless of the answer, your specific example won't work anyway due to the rules for combining effects of the same name.

Answer (score 6):

### You can’t use the same infusion twice

The Infusing an Item part of the Infuse item feature (E:RftLW p. 57) includes

> each of your infusions can be in only one object at a time.

so you can't use it on both your shield and armour.

You can't get around this by knowing the same infusion twice, as (E:RftLW p. 61)

> Unless an infusion's description says otherwise, you
> can't learn an infusion more than once.

And the only infusion with such an exception is Replicate Magic Item.

Comment: are you sure this isn't meant to mean that you cant have the same infusion slot extend to both a shield and armor though or have an enchantment on 2 weapons using one infusion?

Comment: The text is pretty clear: one object and only one object.

Comment: @lukethecat Infusion slot is maybe not a useful abstraction, the limitation is on number of infused objects, and the rule says you can't have the same infusion on more than one object.